# selecting details from the table based on the where condition on same column with different filtering option

Tags: sql, entity-attribute-value

I am having a table  with  below specified structure

[image: Table structure]

From the table, I just want to **retrieve the product id which is having Ram with value *12* and color with *Blue*.** The expected result is 1.
I tried many queries and it's not sharing the expected result.

What will be the solution?

It's very difficult to manage the separate table for each feature as we have an undefined set of features.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select productid
from t
group by productid
having max(case when feature = 'Ram' then value end) = '12' and
       max(case when feature = 'Color' then value end) = 'Blue';
```

Comment: It's working.But is it possible to Use with "In" keyword?Means I just want to check multiple condition.Like 
having max(case when feature = 'Ram' then value end)  in(''12',13) and
       max(case when feature = 'Color' then value end) in( 'Blue';'White')

Comment: @alenantony . . . Yes, you can use `in` for the `when` clause or for the comparison.

Comment: select productid
from t
group by productid
having max(case when feature = 'Ram' then value end) in ( '12',13) and
       max(case when feature = 'Color' then value end) in( 'Blue','White').It's not returning any value.

Answer (score 0):

use correlated subquery with not exists

```
select distinct product_id from tablename a
where not exists 
     (select 1 from tablename b where a.product_id=b.product_id and feature='Ram' and value<>12)
and not exists 
     (select 1 from tablename c where a.product_id=c.product_id and feature='Color' and value<>'blue')
```